# Adding part of string as word next to it and converting the last word of the line to lower case

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, tr

I want to add part of the string as a word (format ) next to it and then to convert the last word(format ) of the line to lower case

For example I have a line as below

```
<http://example.com/Bob> Alex
```

I need output as

```
<http://example.com/Bob> <Bob> <alex>
```

I tried sed and tr commands but was not successful. Any suggestions will be helpful

Thanks
Pallavi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with awk:

```
awk '{s=gensub(/.*\//,"","g");
      s=gensub(/>.*/,"","g",s);
      printf "%s <%s>",$1,s;
      for(i=2; i < NF; i++)
      {
        printf " %s",$i;
      }
      printf " <%s>\n",tolower($NF);}' input.txt
```

Or:

```
awk '{s=gensub(/.*\//,"","g");
      s=gensub(/>.*/,"","g",s);
      $1=$1" <"s">";
      $NF="<"tolower($NF)">";
      print;}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
<http://example.com/Bob> <Bob> <alex>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
sed 's@\(http://.*/\)\(.*\) \(.*\)@\1\2 \2 \L\3@' <<< "http://example.com/Bob Alex"
```

Giving:

```
http://example.com/Bob Bob alex
```